# How to check if a class is of a certain type, ignoring inheritance?

Tags: c#

Lets say I have a parent class and a child class like this:

```
public class Parent{}
```

```
public class Child : Parent{}
```

Now in some method I want to find classes that are of type `Parent`, but I'm not interested in classes of type `Child`. So lets say I do something like this:

```
var listOfParents = new List<Parent>();

foreach(item in someListOfItems)
{
   if(item is Parent)
   {
      listOfParents.Add(item);
   }

}
```

This would give me all classes of type `Parent`, but also all classes of type `Child`, since it implements `Parent`. How could I go about only retrieving the classes of type `Parent` while ignoring all subclasses? I also want to avoid doing lots of `if` checks like `if (item is Parent && !(item is Child)` since this could get messy if there's lots of classes implementing `Parent`.

Comment: Note that, while this is possible, this would violate many OO principles, including the substitution principle that states that you should be able to use a instance of a subclass in every place where you use the parent class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-5.0):

```
if(item.GetType() == typeof(Parent))
```

Note that this will throw `NullReferenceException` if `item` is `null` unlike type checking with `is`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to GuruStron answer. This might remove also the null case.

```
if(item?.GetType() == typeof(Parent))
```